# How to make a backup SDcard image when I can't find the device name using lsblk?

Tags: ubuntu, sd-card, dd

I've just installed Ubuntu and running with Windows 10. I've a linux SD card that is recognized as D: under windows, and I am able to mount in Ubuntu and access it's content using the following commands:
sudo mkdir /mnt/d
sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d

I desire to make a copy of the image using dd, so I need it's name. However, there are no devices shown in /dev directory, or anywhere else I've looked. For example I'd expect to see something like /dev/sda so that I can execute dd -fi=/dev/sda -fo=~backup.img , but how can I do that without knowing the fi name?

When trying to use lsblk nothing shows and I receive the following response:
lsblk: failed to access sysfs directory: /sys/dev/block: No such file or directory

Comment: Maybe this will work: https://superuser.com/a/839508/432690

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the useful link Kamil. Although a useful comment for trying to do the task, the link doesn't provide insight for solving the problem of finding a device ID in the Ubuntu Linux VM. I experience the problem with Ubuntu and Cygwin both running with Windows 10. Booting the same machine as native linux does allow visibility of the device ID so dd can be used. Somehow, Windows 10 must be limiting access to the Linux VM environmet, having to access it through Windows only when the device is mounted.

### Summarizing the comments in the provided link that some might find useful:

### WinDD - operates on partitions, not on the entire device.

Win32 DiskImager - writes images to disk, but doesn't make dd compatible image files.

Chocolatey - not a solution in itself, and packages installed will have the same limitations.

BusyBox - looks promising, as eg uses assigned partition letter.

Rufus - useful for creating bootable images, but not making a backup image.

Comment: It's possible `dd` for Windows [can access the entire device](https://superuser.com/a/942213/432690). And I say "possible" instead of "a fact" only because I haven't tested.